# edge detection using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    laplacia = cv2.Laplacian(frame, cv2.CV_64F)

    cv2.imshow('original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('laplacian', laplacia)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k==27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

## I am getting this error

```
#laplacia = cv2.Laplacian(frame, cv2.CV_64F)
cv2.error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:981: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function cv::Mat::locateROI
```

Comment: you cannot put a colour image into cv2.Laplacian(). convert it to grayscale

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.Laplacian()` won't work with Color images.

You can go through OpenCV Documentation for knowing more..[Image Gradients](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html)

You must convert the frame you have captured to gray scale and then apply `Laplacian`

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

You can convert to gray scale as shown above..

Comment: Sreeram, I still got the same error after converting to grayscale.

Comment: Can you capture image from the camera and display it.??

Comment: Yes, I did that.